# How do you explain the sentence "What do you make of the argument that..."?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, phrase-usage

At first I thought that the sentence "What do you make of the argument that..." is just to ask someone for his opinion on something. However, I have also seen some translation explain that such sentence is asking someone to provide arguments to support something.

e.g. "What do you make of the argument that allowing more immigrants into our country is unavoidable?"
Does that mean: (A)What are your thoughts about "allowing more immigrants into our country is unavoidable"? (for example, do you support this opinion or not?); or (B)How do you make the argument to support the opinion that "allowing more immigrants into our country is unavoidable"?

Comment: I'm flagging this for closure as off-topic (no research/ELL), since the meaning and usage of [make of](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/make%20of) can easily be found online. Natalie, you may not be aware that our other site [ell.se] is the best place to look for answers on English questions that a fluent speaker would find trivial. If you have a question for ELL, be sure to read their guidance on [what you can ask](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). :-)

Answer (score 2):

It’s an idiomatic expression generally used to ask about what someone thinks about something:

***[what do you make of (something):](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/what+do+you+make+of)***

> What is your analysis or opinion of (something)?
>
> - A: "What do you make of the new guy?" B: "He's a little quirky, but I think he's genuinely nice.
> - A: "What do you make of this hole here?" B: "Could be termite damage."

(The Free Dictionary )

Comment: That's for the OP to research out, though.